# Interpreting an R code that uses hclust function

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Could you help me better understand this code below that I saw? See that there is information about some properties, and the `hclust` function is also used. But I didn't understand the output `p = 12`, what represents? By any chance is the maximum number of clusters that can be generated for this data? Could you help me understand?

```
library(geosphere)

Points_properties<-structure(list(Propertie=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29), Latitude = c(-24.781624, -24.775017, -24.769196, 
                                               -24.761741, -24.752019, -24.748008, -24.737312, -24.744718, -24.751996, 
                                               -24.724589, -24.8004, -24.796899, -24.795041, -24.780501, -24.763376, 
                                               -24.801715, -24.728005, -24.737845, -24.743485, -24.742601, -24.766422, 
                                               -24.767525, -24.775631, -24.792703, -24.790994, -24.787275, -24.795902, 
                                               -24.785587, -24.787558), Longitude = c(-49.937369, 
                                                                                                  -49.950576, -49.927608, -49.92762, -49.920608, -49.927707, -49.922095, 
                                                                                                  -49.915438, -49.910843, -49.899478, -49.901775, -49.89364, -49.925657, 
                                                                                                  -49.893193, -49.94081, -49.911967, -49.893358, -49.903904, -49.906435, 
                                                                                                  -49.927951, -49.939603, -49.941541, -49.94455, -49.929797, -49.92141, 
                                                                                                  -49.915141, -49.91042, -49.904772, -49.894034)), row.names = c(NA, -29L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"))

coordinates<-subset(Points_properties,select=c("Latitude","Longitude"))
d<-distm(coordinates[,2:1])
d<-as.dist(d)
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")

  p<-1
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, p) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))
  
  while (min(nclusters)>1) {
    p<-p+1
    clusters<-cutree(fit.average, p) 
    nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))}
  p<-p-1
> p
[1] 12
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `p` is the minimum number of clusters that will give you at least 1 group with only 1 member in it.

```
nclusters <- matrix(table(clusters))
```

`nclusters` store the number of members in each cluster as a matrix.

```
while (min(nclusters)>1) {
```

The while loop will stop when `nclusters` is 1.

Comment: Thanks @Fursham. I was looking at the code and your answer, and I came up with another idea. Does the code consider solutions to have a cluster with at least 2 properties? So, is 12 the number of solutions that considers at least 2 properties?

Comment: You can print out `nclusters` before and after the while loop and you will find that the it starts as a 1x1 matrix with a value of 29, and ends with a 13x1  matrix with the first row having a value of 1.

Comment: That means there are 12 clusters with at least 2 properties, right? Because in the first there is only 1 observation.